# Término para persona que le gusta imponer sus términos unilateralmente

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sinónimos

Busco un término para persona que le gusta imponer sus términos, es decir, no le gusta que los demás no estén alineados con su mirada condescendiente de lo contrario al cuestionarse podría insegurizarse y con eso perdería terreno y quedaría indefenso incluso ante el mismo y ése/ésa ya no sería él/ella. Es como si viera a las personas como un animal al cual amansar, si se comportan distinto de como él los tenía catalogados entonces es porque no los domesticó lo suficiente o tendrá que moldearlos sin demora, puede hacerlo inconscientemente, en forma patológica, en broma o como una conducta sistemática para dirigir una agrupación o partido.

Es como decir: Mi visión de las cosas es más fidedigna que la tuya, si me demuestras lo contrario entonces nuestra relación se va a ver afectada sí o sí porque en definitiva no me importa lo que pienses o hagas si no coincide con la idea que tenía de ti en un comienzo porque debido a eso me acerqué no a la que ahora me está defraudando, no necesito a otra persona.

¿Esquemática? ¿Totalitaria?

Esquemático
2. adj. Que tiende a interpretar cualquier asunto sin percibir sus matices.

Si se buscan los sinónimos, entonces dice exactamente lo contrario: Detallado, exhaustivo, minucioso, pormenorizado, circunstanciado.

¿Rígida? ¿Restrictiva? ¿Taxativa? ¿Patológica?¿ prepotente? ¿Despótica? ¿Tendenciosa? ¿Subjetivo? ¿Dominante? ¿Autoritaria? Biased person? Prejuiciosa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente no haya un término que incluya todas las características que has descrito en la pregunta. Pero lo más cercano que se me ocurre es **dominante**, que según el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/dominante?m=form) significa, entre otras cosas

> 2. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que quiere avasallar a otras.

y [avasallar](https://dle.rae.es/avasallar?m=form) significa

> 1. tr. Sujetar, rendir o someter a obediencia.

El conocido (aunque no aceptado por todos) modelo de comportamiento [DISC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Moulton_Marston#El_modelo_te%C3%B3rico_DISC), de
William Moulton Marston, incluye el rasgo **dominante** como uno de los cuatro "ejes" que definen la personalidad. Según [varios](https://www.pilarjerico.com/dominante-influyente-concienzudo-o-estable-como-eres-tu/) [blogs](https://www.psicoactiva.com/blog/personalidad-dominante/), una persona dominante según el modelo DISC

> proyecta su energía al mundo y utiliza la razón para alcanzar sus objetivos. Es confiable, tenaz, exigente, orientado al poder y puede ser agresivo en las formas. Aquí están las personas que les gusta decir lo que el resto ha de hacer.

Una manera coloquial de llamar a una persona dominante es **[mandón](https://dle.rae.es/mand%C3%B3n?m=form)**, que según el DLE es

> 1. adj. Que ostenta demasiado su autoridad y manda más de lo que le toca. U. t. c. s.

Comment: Agregar que también he escuchado avasallador que está en la definición de dominante pero como verbo.